# Where is the exception information when I return InternalServerError from a Web Api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm calling one Web Api (.NET Framework) from another (.NET Core). If the called one returns an InternalServerError(exception), how do I access that exception from the calling code?

The called one does this:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAccountTransactions()
{
    try
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         return InternalServerError(e);
    }
}
```

The calling one does this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
```

...but when I add the `response` to the watch window in Visual Studio, I can't find the exception information.

Comment: Isn't it in response body?

Comment: @dropoutcoder I very well could be blind, but I don't see it.

Comment: Or maybe it is because older ASP.NET needs to handle exceptions...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/

Answer (score 0):

Using Fiddler, I confirmed that the exception was included in the response body but it took some work to extract it.

See [How can I retrieve passed exception from HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode, Exception)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865487/how-can-i-retrieve-passed-exception-from-httpresponsemessagehttpstatuscode-exc/28904410#28904410)

I tested this answer posted there with .NET Framework, but not with .NET Core.

```
if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode){
    HttpError error = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<HttpError>().Result;
}
```